# Shared cookie in different domain Service (WCF)

Tags: c#, wcf, session-cookies

i have 2 web sites that consumes a service (WCF). The user's authentication is done in the service to access one site. How to make this authentication to access both sites? Can i store a cookie in the service (WCF) and access both sites?

How can i do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify what authentication scheme you are using? SSO? FormsAuth, OWIN?

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple. Once you have called FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie in your application. A cookie is created/encrypted and given to the user. 
For another website to consume that cookie for auth purposes,

1. it must be by the same cookie name/domain
2. can be decrypted,
3. and is still valid.

To do this, you merely need to ensure the keys and names are the same in the web config for each application: for example from: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/eb0zx8fc(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/eb0zx8fc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" >
      <!-- The name, protection, and path attributes must match 
           exactly in each Web.config file. -->
      <forms loginUrl="login.aspx"
        name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" 
        protection="All"  
        path="/" 
        domain="contoso.com" 
        timeout="30" />
    </authentication>

    <!-- Validation and decryption keys must exactly match and cannot
         be set to "AutoGenerate". The validation and decryption
         algorithms must also be the same. -->
    <machineKey
      validationKey="C50B3C89CB21F4F1422FF158A5B42D0E8DB8CB5CDA1742572A487D9401E3400267682B202B746511891C1BAF47F8D25C07F6C39A104696DB51F17C529AD3CABE" 
      decryptionKey="8A9BE8FD67AF6979E7D20198CFEA50DD3D3799C77AF2B72F" 
      validation="SHA1" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```